# Shiny app with ggplot map - polygons colors don't match user inputs

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to build a simple map app with Shiny and ggplot2. It works as follow:

- user selects a country
- the app loads a shape file and gives a list of input fields for adm1 country regions
- user inputs a numeric value for each region (fields are initially filled with random values)
- all values from input fields are collected in a vector, merged to the map data and given as a `fill` argument to the `ggplot()` function

The problem is that ggplot doesn't seem to interpret correctly the input values for each regions. Plus, colors on the map don't change when input values are modified through the UI. I believe the  `indicator` vector fed to the `fill` argument is not correctly interpreted/passed.

Thank you for your suggestions.

*Note: in the code below, the shapefiles are sourced on the UCDavis website for reproducibility. I usually store them locally.*

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(

 sidebarPanel(      
  selectInput("ctry", "Country:",
              list("Burkina Faso"="BFA","Ethiopia"="ETH","Ghana"="GHA",
                   "Kenya"="KEN","Malawi"="MWI","Mali"="MLI"), selected="ETH"), 
  uiOutput("sliders")

 ),   
 mainPanel(
   plotOutput('map', width = "100%")
 )
)
)
)
```

**server.R**

```
x<-c("ggplot2","sp","maptools","rgdal","rgeos","scales","grid","gridExtra","plyr") 
lapply(x, require, character.only=T)
rm(x)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 

 gadm<-reactive ({
 load(paste0("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/",input$ctry,"_adm1.RData")) #load country shapefile
 gadm@data$id <- rownames(gadm@data)
 gadm.df      <- fortify(gadm)
 gadm.df      <- join(gadm.df,gadm@data, by="id")
 return(gadm.df)
 })

 output$sliders <- renderUI({
   regions    <- unique(gadm()$NAME_1)  #get list of region names
   numRegions <- length(regions)        #get number of regions
   lapply(1:numRegions, function(i) {   #generate 1 input field per region
   numericInput(paste0("reg",i),        #with random values
               label = regions[i], value = round(runif(1, 1.0, 7.5),2),
               step=0.1) })
 })

 mapdata<- reactive({
   regions    <- unique(gadm()$NAME_1)  #get list of region names
   numRegions <- length(regions)        #get number of regions
   indicator  <- input$reg1             #initate vector with first value of user inputs
   for (i in 2:numRegions)(
   indicator<-c(indicator,eval(paste0("input$reg",i)))  #collect all user inputs values in a vector
   )
   indicator <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(indicator,regions)))#attribute region name to user input values
   colnames(indicator)<-c("indicator","NAME_1")
   merge(gadm(), indicator, by="NAME_1")                  #merge it with map data
   })

   themap <- function() {    
     ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=mapdata(), 
                        aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=as.numeric(indicator) )) + 
     scale_fill_gradient("test",low="#99d8c9", high="#00441b") +
     geom_path(data=mapdata(), 
            aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color='grey', size=0.15, alpha=0.6) + 
     coord_map()
   }

   output$map<-renderPlot({  themap()  }, height = 700 )

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the expression `eval(paste0("input$reg",i))` returns you not the content of input$regN, but the string "input$regN". You can obtain the desired element of input by using double brackets:

```
x<-c("ggplot2","sp","maptools","rgdal","rgeos","scales","grid","gridExtra","plyr") 
lapply(x, require, character.only=T)
rm(x)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 

 gadm<-reactive ({
 load(paste0(input$ctry,"_adm1.RData")) #load country shapefile
 gadm@data$id <- rownames(gadm@data)
 gadm.df      <- fortify(gadm)
 gadm.df      <- join(gadm.df,gadm@data, by="id")
 return(gadm.df)
 })

 output$sliders <- renderUI({
   regions    <- unique(gadm()$NAME_1)  #get list of region names
   numRegions <- length(regions)        #get number of regions
   lapply(1:numRegions, function(i) {   #generate 1 input field per region
   numericInput(paste0("reg",i),        #with random values
               label = regions[i], value = round(runif(1, 1.0, 7.5),2),
               step=0.1) })
 })

 mapdata<- reactive({
   regions    <- unique(gadm()$NAME_1)  #get list of region names
   numRegions <- length(regions)        #get number of regions

   indicator  <- sapply(seq_along(regions),function(i) input[[paste0('reg',i)]])
   if (any(is.null(unlist(indicator)))) return()
   indicator <- as.data.frame(cbind(indicator,regions))#attribute region name to user input values

   colnames(indicator)<-c("indicator","NAME_1")
   merge(gadm(), indicator, by="NAME_1")                  #merge it with map data
   })

   themap <- function() {    
     d <- mapdata()
     if (is.null(d)) return()
     ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=d, 
                        aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=as.numeric(indicator) )) + 
     scale_fill_gradient("test",low="#99d8c9", high="#00441b") +
     geom_path(data=d, 
            aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color='grey', size=0.15, alpha=0.6) + 
     coord_map()
   }

   output$map<-renderPlot({  themap()  }, height = 700 )

})
```

Note that mapdata() might be called ahead of output$sliders, so input$regN might not exist at the moment of the mapdata() evaluation. To avoid the related problems, I inserted couple of checks in the code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marat Talipov for finding this solution!